# Do we need [fashion]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I saw that a tag for [fashion](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fashion) was created and used on [one question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/whats-the-best-way-to-keep-your-shirt-tucked-in), but it doesn't really have to do with lifehacks as far as I can tell. Something like [clothing](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing) seems to fit a lot better.

Should we go ahead and burn the tag, or does someone have an idea of a type of lifehack that it's applicable to?

Comment: Clothing should cover it...

Comment: As Tim said, the [tag:fashion] is sub-tag of [tag:clothing].

But question about clothing don't always assume fashion. This tag makes the the question more specific and it is clear that you are not talking about. As for examples: let's see. And, by the way, I think that existing question is a very good example.

Comment: @nicael So are you saying that fashion is a good description of the lifehack being asked about?

Comment: Why not? There could be a q about how to make smth look in another way, fashionably, and a hacky solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, it's not necessary for that question. I've removed it from the question, not because it's a bad tag, but because it doesn't belong on that specific question. It should self-delete within a day.

If we end up receiving questions that require the tag, we can recreate it at that time.